# Difficulties with placement properties in maplex labeling

Tags: labeling, maplex

I'm working in ArcGIS 10.2.2 and am having two difficulties with labelling using the Maplex Engine.

The first problem is that I have two labels that I can't seem to put any additional space in between. (The circled area on the right side of the attached image.) Both labels are labelling features in the same class in the same layer. The feature weight is 0, the label buffer is maxed out at 50, with a hard constraint, yet they are placed right next to each other. What I would prefer is to get the Starr Street label moved to the left so that it is the fairly open area to the left of Newhall Street, but the label won't seem to move there.

My other issue is that I have one north-south street where the label runs top to bottom instead of bottom to top, as all the other streets are. I assume this is because this is the only street on a curve, and the maplex engine determined that this is the best way to place it using a centered curve. Is there any way to force the label to run the other way instead?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the street placement option enabled? https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/09/13/what-does-the-maplex-label-engines-street-placement-option-do/

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response, but I do have it enabled..

Comment: "default value of 0, the words in the label will be spread evenly across the length of the street feature." http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Labeling_streets

Comment: The "spread words along street" option isn't showing up for me. I have ArcMap 10.2.2 as opposed to the Version 9.x in that link if that makes a difference.